# iOS XMLHttpRequest's responseXML Is null When responseText.length > 10000000

Tags: javascript, ios, xmlhttprequest, mobile-safari, ipad-2

A Web application of mine has begun failing suddenly.  My XMLHttpRequest's responseXML is null in Safari on iOS, even though the desktop and Windows Phone browsers I tested could parse the XML and get a non-null responseXML.  After lots of guessing and checking tonight, I discovered iOS's responseXML is null when responseText's length is greater than 10000000 (10 million characters).  I am testing on iOS 9.0.2 with an iPad 2.

Does anyone know how to exceed this 10000000-character limit?  I can't find any documentation about this quirk.  Thank you.

Comment: Likely related to CVE-2008-4226. Chromium had this issue for about a month before fixing it. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=528078